# Where should I declare the styles on my page? And why?

Tags: html, css

Does it matter where I declare my CSS styles on my page?

Is this:

```
<style>

    div{
        height: 50px;
        width: 200px;
    }

</style>

<body>

    <div>This div</div>

</body>
```

Different to this?

```
<body>

    <div>This div</div>

</body>


<style>

    div{
        height: 50px;
        width: 200px;
    }

</style>
```

If so, how?

I've seen examples of both and never really noticed any significant changes in how long the styles take to kick in on page load. Although, about 90% of the time, styles are declared at the top of the page.

Personally, I much prefer including a separate stylesheet to avoid adding styles to a page in this fashion.

Comment: inner CSS file is only used in the same file. But in case of outer CSS file, you can use it in various page. It is the real factor. It also helps to better looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Place it at start**

You should place the `STYLE` element in the `HEAD` helps the pages load more quickly because the page can then `render as the HTML loads`.

When a web browser reads a web page, it reads it in the order that the HTML is written. So when your style sheet comes first, that is what is read first. Then, when the browser gets to the HTML, it already knows how to style it and so doesn’t have to wait to load the CSS before displaying the content.

**Why Not Put Style Sheets at the Bottom of the Page**

When you place a style sheet at the bottom, this prevents many browsers, especially Internet Explorer, from doing `progressive rendering`. Internet Explorer even blocks `rendering of the page` until all the styles are added, so that it doesn’t have to redraw the page. This means that customers will see a blank white page until all the elements and styles have been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to put stylesheets in head.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        div{
            height: 50px;
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
```

It is recommended because when you have the CSS declared before  starts, your styles has actually loaded already. So very quickly users see something appear on their screen (e.g. background colors). If not, users see blank screen for some time before the CSS reaches the user.

Also, if you leave the the styles somewhere in the , the browser has to re-render the page (new and old when loading) when the styles declared has been parsed.

Answer (score 0):

When you add styles to the html page, they are loaded as the page loads and parsed accordingly in that order. Like in first example, the style loads first and then the elements which is meaningless. In the second one, the elements load first with the default styling and then they are styled.
Adding files to a separate stylesheet waits for the page to load and then displays the styles. In very slow connections or heavy pages, the difference is significant.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your stylesheet in head

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                ...
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            ....
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `style` element should apply to the whole document, wherever it is placed, however it is common practice to always put it in the `head` element. I would not be surprised if browser handling is a bit flaky if you put it in other places.

Note that `html5` allows you to specify the scoped attribute for the `style` element, which means that it will only apply to the parent element of the style element and all its children.

By the way, usual practice is to put the css in a separate file and use the `<link>` tag to include the CSS in your document. This way you can share the css across multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first alternative, `style` before `body`, is valid, according to any CSS specification. No tags are allowed after the end tag `</body>`, except the end tag `</html>`.

Although browsers are permissive, there is usually no reason to even think of deviating from the correct order. In some authoring situations, you might be unable to inject a `style` element where it belongs (the `head` part), but even then, it should be placed before the end tag `</body>`.